# Can a sentence be syntactically correct but grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In my opinion, since syntax tells us how to arrange words in a sentence to get meaning, it is not concerned with morphology.
 For example, **"The cooler are off."** will be a syntactically correct, grammatically incorrect sentence. Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: Your opinion is incorrect. Syntax and morphology are both part of grammar; syntax is the grammar that operates outside of the word and morphology is the grammar that operates inside of it. They often share responsibilities in the same construction, like English modals (_must/have to; should/ought to; can/able to_ etc.) or transitive sense verbs (_see/look at; hear/listen to_).

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/whats-the-difference-between-grammar-and-syntax

Comment: The error in your example is incorrect verb conjugation, which is a syntax error. So it's not syntactically correct.