# What type of error is this?

Tags: errors

What's a name for mistakes like in the following sentence: "time flies even faster as a parent"?

*Requested edit to clarify where the error is*: **time as a parent** is the subject in the sentence above, which was not the intended meaning. "Time flies even faster for a parent" or "For a parent, time flies even faster" would better communicate the intended meaning.

Comment: Hi Yan F, welcome to English Language & Usage. If you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do!), please make sure you take the [Tour].  :-)

Comment: Regarding your question, where's the *grammatical* error in your example sentence?

Comment: Your question was closed because it was unclear, because you used 'grammatical' error when there doesn't seem to be a grammatical error at all. There is definitely ambiguity, but that's not an error (it's poor style).

Comment: @Mitch: ["Grammatical error is a term used in prescriptive grammar to describe an instance of faulty, unconventional, or controversial usage, such as a ​misplaced modifier or an inappropriate verb tense."](https://www.thoughtco.com/grammatical-error-usage-1690911)

Comment: @YanF. Sure, but none of those happened here. Parsing ambiguity through amphiboly is not a grammatical error.

Comment: @Mitch, wouldn't an amphiboly be actually ambiguous, while the intended meaning of the given sentence is clear?

Comment: @YanF. I'm not sure what you're getting at. Amphiboly is use of polysemy intentionally, a kind of ambiguity. Ambiguity, whether of lexical semantics or of parsing, is not an error. "Time flies fast as a parent" intending that "Parents and time both are flying objecs, and one flies as fast as a another" is silly (or nonsensical), but is definitely perfectly fine syntax (what grammar refers to).

Comment: @Mitch, what I am getting at is **grammatical error** is a term used in prescriptive grammar, as per above, and that the rules of prescriptive grammar ["...address such linguistic aspects as spelling, pronunciation, vocabulary, syntax, **and semantics**."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription).

Comment: @YanF. Oh. That's what you take from that site? It's not how ELU understands the term grammar. Grammar is understood here to mean syntax, the order of words and . Punctuation and spelling come under orthography. Meaning of sentences and words is semantics. 'Prescriptive grammar' as a set phrase is a term of that guys own making and you're taking it to mean something special that I don't understand. I understand those two words together to not be an idiom or special thing but to mean a grammar (or syntactic rules) that are intended to be used prescriptively (the _only_ rules one _should use).

Comment: @Mitch, I did not know that about ELU. Russian is my native language and Russian semantics is part of morphology which, in turn, is part of grammar. Also, per [this accepted answer at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/29580/237964), the grammar consists of syntax and morphology and sometimes also phonology and semantics. Regardless, I edited my question once again to make it less limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're referring to an [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier) because time is not a parent. Of course, the implied identity of the parent is the speaker:

> [I find that] time flies even faster as a parent [than it would otherwise].

That is,

> **I**, as a parent, find that subjective time moves relatively fast.

Comment: I accept the edited answer. Dangling modifier it is. The Wiki article is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Time flies even faster as a parent."  Has no errors in it.  "Time flies" is a very familiar metaphor used when people communicate about how they feel about the passage of time.

"Time flies like an arrow.  Fruit flies like a banana."

Comment: Time can fly, can it be a parent, though? :)

Comment: @YanF. you're confusing grammar with semantics. Yes, time can be a parent, if that's the metaphor being used.

Comment: @Chappo, but it's not being used in the given sentence.

Comment: @YanF. I see you’ve edited your question to remove the reference to grammar.

Comment: @Chappo, yes, per discussion with Mitch. Not sure why the question is still locked, though.